# Magento EE order Archive

Tags: orders, magento-enterprise, ee-1.11

Can anyone please mention how the Magento EE's order archiving feature works. Does it require the default magento CRON enabled(Currently we run it disabled). And how do we know that orders are archived after we enable the setting. also how it will look e.g sales order admin page after the archive.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the `sales_flat_order` table that holds the orders there is also an other table called `sales_flat_order_grid`.
That table holds the records that you see displayed in the backend in the orders grid.
It basically holds the same rows as in the `sales_flat_order` table but with fewer columns.
This is a boost in performance.
The archive feature in EE creates an other table similar to `sales_flat_order_grid` (I don't remember the table name).
When you turn on the order archive, the orders that satisfy the conditions you set for archiving are moved from the `sales_flat_order_grid` table to the new one. This means that when looking at the order grid you will see only the not archived orders.
If the archiving worked you should see an additional menu in `Sales` with the archived orders where you will have a grid with the orders that satisfy the archive conditions.

**be careful**: If you do any operations on the order collection you will still be able to access the archived orders also. They still remain in the base table `sales_flat_order`. (Learned that the hard way).

Comment: Marius, can you develop a feed for your SE answers that compile and print themselves into a reference guide? Where on earth is the official Magento guide for this stuff?

Comment: @RickBuczynski. Ha ha. You can do that too: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=magento

Comment: Except one requirement that isn't met: it must also print itself onto paper ;)

Comment: Write it to a file and send it to the printer. Problem solved.

Comment: Hesitating on the urge to upvote there.

Comment: The table name (that you couldn't recall) that the orders get archived to is `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.  In other words, orders are archived from `sales_flat_order_grid` to `enterprise_sales_order_grid_archive`.